# How to have a TextBox control fill a Split Container panel?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox, splitter

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Professional (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel) with no updates showing in Windows Update.  When I drop a TextBox control into a Split Container panel, make it Multiline, then Dock in Parent = Fill, it shrinks down to 1 pixel wide and disappears.  Of course, at runtime it is invisible.

Is this a bug?  Is there a fix?  I actually don't need text input - what I want is to display text in a resizable panel, with scroll bars.  I could perhaps put code on the events (SizeChanged, SplitterMoved, SplitterMoving...) but that's an ugly solution.  Is that the only one?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I didn't realize I had put a Flow Layout container inside the Split Container panel.  This was preventing it from filling the panel.